# Pass variable into Angular filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I'm writing an Angular app with some dynamic pages. I've got a `stateParam` named `currentCategory` which gives back an integer for current category's id. Is there a way to pass this integer into an Angular filter, since I only want to show current page's category?

This would be straightforward, but returns an syntax error.

`<div ng-repeat="category in categories | filter:{cat_id:{{currentCategory}}}:true">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the interpolate expressions (`{{ }}`) and it should work:

```
filter:{cat_id:currentCategory}:true
```

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't give a syntax error anymore, but also doesn't show content.

``{{ currentCategory }}`` results into '1'

The following code block doesn't show anything but ng-repeat tags

``<div ng-repeat="category in categories | filter:{cat_id:currentCategory}:true">{{ category.name_en }}</div>``

If I'd type it static id does give does display the category name

``<div ng-repeat="category in categories | filter:{cat_id:1}:true">{{ category.name_en }}</div>``

Comment: probably currentCategory doesn't get set correctly. Anyways, can you create a plunker?

Comment: Created a plunkr (http://embed.plnkr.co/dN4Jt7VmCOnwcq5ThZn1/) and it worked. Issue was, that Angulary was wrapping ``currentCategory`` around spaces. Stripping them out did the trick. Thanks!